# How to know how many posts match the query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table called `rivers`, I need to know how many rivers that are not geometrically simple:

```
SELECT rivers.name,ST_IsSimple(rivers.the_geom),rivers. svg
FROM rivers
ORDER BY ST_IsSimple(rivers.the_geom) ASC
```

[image]

This code returns a table contains ST_IsSimple column with values either are 0 or 1. However, the table can only list the first 5 posts, so what should I do if I want to know the total number of matched posts (i.e.rivers that are not geometrically simple )? Thanks!

Comment: count(rivers.name) isnt working? (is name unique?)

Comment: select count(rivers.name) from rivers where ST_IsSimple(the_geom) = 'f'; Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
SELECT rivers.name,ST_IsSimple(rivers.the_geom),rivers. svg, COUNT(rivers.name) AS Totals
FROM rivers
GROUP BY rivers.name,ST_IsSimple(rivers.the_geom),rivers. svg
ORDER BY ST_IsSimple(rivers.the_geom);
```

Comment: I am not sure this answers the question, and mixing a name and count like this is questionable.

Comment: i was just telling him the logic. Right implementation is up to the the user. As far as i m concern SO is just for their help not for writing the codes for them.